# Installing codeBlock

Tags: c, codeblocks

This is my first time of trying to develop with C programming language. I tried installing codeblock on my window 8 operating system, but whenever I run the codeblock program I get this error in the image below[image: Codeblock Error]

I installed codeblock hopping that it would install the compiler alongside, but I was disappointed. I do not know how to install the standalone compiler, I checked it up online, but I really do not know from where to start, and I do not know if the problem is with my system. I would appreciate help on how to make my codeblock work properly or any other suggestions. Thanks all.

Comment: Try looking on to this question stackoverflow.com/questions/17476526/… and also stackoverflow.com/questions/17457862/…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running CB for the first time, you are prompted with a "Compiler auto-detection" dialog/window.
 
It looks like you chose the WRONG COMPILER -> GCC for MSP430 micro controller!
Correct that to GCC/MinGW
EDIT - 1: Its usually the first option on the "Compiler auto-detection" dialog
EDIT - 2
I think you may also have selected the wrong compiler for your CB project
For C project, Follow these steps:-

1. Create a new project -> Console application for C/C++,
2. Skip the first page, click next
3. Provide a title & path, click next
4. at compiler selection screen, select **"GNU GCC Compiler"** instead of **"GNU GCC Compiler for MSP430"**

Comment: If you downloaded the file -> "codeblocks-12.11mingw-setup.exe", then the compiler auto-detect window will mark the firs option (GCC) as "detected". Also note that having multiple versions of MinGW in your path is a bad idea.

Comment: I did what you asked, it stopped showing the error, but now I cant make a new project, it displays an error that says "Couldn't save project<invalid path> (maybe the file is write-protected?)"

Comment: Try giving the project a VALID filename and saving to your home directory

Comment: Thanks, the folder it was saving too had some admin restrictions

Answer (score 1):

The compiler might not be included in the Code::Blocks you downloaded (if you got codeblocks-12.11-setup.exe). There's another downloadable binary ([codeblocks-12.11mingw-setup.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/12.11/Windows/codeblocks-12.11mingw-setup.exe)) that includes the MinGW environment with the GNU GCC compiler. You might want to try that one.

Comment: This is exactly the code block I downloaded. It still gives the same problem

Comment: Try restarting your computer: sometimes changes to environment variables are only applied at startup or login time.

Comment: Can you run GCC from a command prompt? It is probably installed at C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe

Comment: Nope I do not know how to do that

Comment: You can also check that Code::Blocks has identified the correct compiler by looking at the "Toolchain executables" tab in the setting for the GNU GCC Compiler under the menu "Settings/Complier"

Comment: @jpw, I got the GCC compiler and ran the setup. created a folder on my root directory just like this "C:\MinGW32\ ". From the settings tab I entered the compiler option in code block and choose the directory of the compiler installation, it still did not work

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge I don't know Code::Blocks well enough to help you further, but if you're not set on using CB and don't mind using Java software I'd recommend [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads). There is a C/C++ bundle and you can find detailed instructions on how to set it up [here](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/cpp-setup-instructions.html)

Comment: Oh thanks.. I would try that out now, I have netbeans installed on my system already

Comment: @jpw, the netbeans is refusing to compile, it is requesting a make command and its refusing to compile

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge If you followed the instructions I linked to 'make' should be properly set up; you can check under "Tools/Options/C/C++" that there is a path filled in to "Make Command" (it should be C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe is MinGW is installed under C:\MinGW).

Answer (score 1):

Step-1 : Visit [www.mingw.org/](http://www.mingw.org/)

Step-2 : Download and install all package.(Specially mark the the file starting from mingw)

Step-3 : Goto to installation and Apply Changes.

Step-4 : Now open your code block

Step-5 : Goto to Setting->Compiler

Step-6 : Now click toolchain executable AND SELECT GNU GCC COMPILER

Step-7: Click autodetect and then OK

I hope this will definitely work out, All the best

Answer (score 0):

Just goto setting > compiler  and click on "restore default" . Then yes and ok .Done . I think  it will never occur the error.